# Find Source Files for OpenGL on Host

Tags: ubuntu, find, opengl

I just installed openGL on ubuntu and would like to tweak some of its source files I use in order to print certain results of some calculations done.

I found the header file I needed using:

```
cd /
sudo find . -name freeglut_std.h
```

I would like to find the corresponding source file. Which is `freeglut_std.c` I guess. I tried the same command:

```
sudo find . -name freeglut_std.c
```

But nothing was found. How can I find it so I can add a few `printf`'s to the source file?

EDIT: this is the short tutorial I followed in order to install openGL: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345177

Comment: how did you install the source files?

Comment: @user1794469, this is the tutorial I followed: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345177

Answer (score 0):

If you are building something and want the results of some calculation you can usually do this just before and/or just after the library call you are making.

However, if you do want to edit the source directly for better control or learning you need the full source. The `freeglut3-dev` package includes the library to link against and the header files needed to develop, but not the source since you don't generally need to edit anything. (See [file list](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/freeglut3-dev/filelist). You didn't say which architecture you were using but it's the same idea either way.) To edit the actual files you will need to get the [source from the project itself](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freeglut/?source=typ_redirect).

Note: I don't see a `freeglut_std.c` file in the source either. To find the code you want to edit you will need to search for the function call you want to edit rather than the file.